# What is the best way to save keras models and tokenizers for NLP?

Tags: keras, save, load, pickle, tokenize

I have been using the following snippets for many time:

For saving:

```
# saving model and tokenizer
with open('./static_models/tokenizer.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(tokenizer, handle, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

model.save('./static_models/model.h5')
```

For loading:

```
model = models.load_model('./static_models/model.h5')

# loading
with open('./static_models/tokenizer.pickle', 'rb') as handle:
    tokenizer = pickle.load(handle)
```

However I have read many times that pickle is not safe, so, what alternatives do we have?